# Android native app in Visual Studio 2015: fatal error : 'vector' file not found

Tags: android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

I am porting some Android work to Visual Studio 2015.

```
I get fatal error : 'vector' file not found on this code line:
    #include <vector>
```

Normally in Windows that would simply mean I haven't included the std namespace or similar.

I downloaded the NDK (I don't think Visual Studio 2015) installs that along with the Android SDK.  I set the environment variable.

Any ideas what I can do next.  I could hard code an include maybe into the project but it just seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when I added some additional C++ includes I inadvertently overwrote some standard includes from the blank project which are:

```
$(Sysroot)\usr\include;$(StlIncludeDirectories)%
(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

It now appears to get past the error.